# Ubuntu 11.10 not showing up in GRUB bootloader after update and restart :(

Tags: grub2

I was using ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell. I installed various useful softwares and ran system update using update manager which ran smoothly and asked me to restart my comp at the end. I restarted it to find that Ubuntu entries were missing from the GRUB bootloader and only memory test and windows are showing up. 
I took a lot of pain in installing various important softwares and cannot afford a re-installation.

Tried to boot from the live cd and installed boot-repair and after running it .. it wasnt working properly .. it was just showing that it was "scanning systems" for more than an hour.

Kindly help.
Thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the Ubuntu Live CD and run a few commands.

First, identify which is the Ubuntu partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Next, mount it (replacing sda2 with the appropriate partition number):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

And finally, reinstall Grub (replacing sda with the appropriate hard drive):

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Now, run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should detect your Ubuntu installation and add it to the Grub menu.

Comment: i have tried these and here are the results ..

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005fa31

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      206848   327886847   163840000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       327886848   651470847   161792000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       651470848   898387967   123458560    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       898390014   976771071    39190529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       898390016   914272255     7941120   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       914274304   976771071    31248384   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda6/mnt

Comment: mount: can't find /dev/sda6/mnt in /etc/fstab

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub -install --root -directory = /mnt/dev/sda4

Comment: sudo: grub: command not found

Comment: sudo update -grub

Comment: sudo: update: command not found

Comment: and on which partition should i reinstall grub? please help ... thanks ..

Comment: Spaces and case are **very** important when entering commands in the Terminal. Judging from your output, here are the exact commands you should run. Try copy/pasting, if possible. 1: `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt` 2: `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` 3: `sudo update-grub`

Comment: thanks a lot for the above instructions ... i could successfully mount the partition and install grub ... but when trying to update grub i got the following error ... please help ..

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub

Comment: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).

Comment: Um... Try rebooting and running `sudo update-grub` from your actual Ubuntu installation, not from the live CD.

Comment: If rebooting works, then there's no point in running update-grub any more, is there?  Better try the 'update-grub' thing in a chroot.  I'll go search for instructions on the Ubuntu Wiki, since I'm not sure I can correctly reproduce them from memory.

Comment: Here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#ChRoot.  Your problem is a broken grub.cfg; there's no need to run grub-install.